# Google tag manager Click tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to do a simple tag that measures the amount of times an element is clicked.

I got into difficulty so I looked to find a video to help because tag manager layout had changed.

I follow the following Free tutorial on Udemy

https://www.udemy.com/google-tag-manager-advanced/

Specifically chapter 8 Button Click - which is a free chapter.   It tells me to setup the following options:

Tag Configuration:

Google Analytics  Tracking ID: {{Tracking ID}}
Track Type: Event
Category: Click
Action:  Homepage CTA Button
Label: (blank)
Value: (value)

Then on the trigger:

Add a new one. 
Name it - click on homepage button

Add “Just Links”

He ticked the wait for tags

The where it said “Enable this trigger when all of thee conditions are true” he selected

Page Path in the drop down menu.

Now here is where my issue is. When I do exactly the same thing, I only have the following options:

Google Analytics Settings 
Page Hostname
Page Path
Page URL
Referrer
New Variable…

Now the new Variable send to to a new window which gives me the following options:

Navigation:
http referrer
URL

Page Variables:
1st-Party Cookie
Custom Javascript
Data Layer Variable
JavaScript Variable

Page Elements:
Auto-Event Variable
DOM Element

Utilities:
Constant 
Custom Event
Environment Name
Google Analytics Settings
Lookup Table 
Random Number

Container Data:
Container ID
Container Version Number
Debug Mode

So how do I setup the trigger to load on every page and track if someone clicks on the element with a CSS ID of menu-item-6825???

Totally lost on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you need:

1) Go to "Variables" menu in the sidebar.

2) Click "Configure"

3) Enable "Click Classes", "Click ID", "Click Element" variable

[image]

After this steps, you need to configure trigger and create condition: `Click ID` - `equals` - `menu-item-6825`. **OR** condition like that: `Click Element` - `matches CSS selector` - `#menu-item-6825`. Both conditions are doing the same thing.

Comment: you are amazing. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I was going mad trying to work this out. 

Have a great day.